# How to pass plaintext into a variable, and check for filenames matching that text

Tags: bash

I'm having issues passing text into BASH and having it exit a while loop if files exist with names matching the entered text, as a means of verifying input. Here's what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cwd=$(pwd)


while [ ! $cwd\/$name1 ]; do 
    echo "Enter normal tabular filename, followed by ENTER:"
    read -e name1

done
```

Lets say the file name entered was foo.tabular, and it so happens that a file named foo.tabular exists in the current directory. How does one cause the while loop to terminate? I've searched and searched for an answer, duplicated questions etc. but to no avail.
As you can probably tell, I'm not well versed in bash, and I have a feeling the answer is staring me in the face. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Nesting loop solutions aren't immediately obvious to me, and I have no idea if this is a scope issue.

*Just thought I'd add that I'm trying to make the loop look for the first occasion where the entered name1 variable "doesn't not" match a filepath in the working directory and exit.

Comment: `[ -f filename ]` tests for existence of *filename* as regular file. Read manual of command `test`. `[` is an alias for `test`.

Comment: tried it with [ -f !$name1 ] , still doesn't exit the loop when I enter a valid filename.

Comment: `[ ! -f "$name1" ]`. Spacing and quotes matter. And btw, use `$PWD` -- much more efficient than running `$(pwd)` to collect the name.

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: btw, running `bash -x yourscript` will log the commands being run, which is generally useful if trying to debug -- that way you can, for instance, pick out the individual `[` command as it's being invoked, and then run it yourself outside of the script, check the exit status, and otherwise inspect behavior in practice.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help Charles and Jean, this seems to have solved my issue. I don't seem to be able to upvote your answers though, I don't think I've got the privileges or something.

Comment: These are all just comments, not answers -- I don't think we have a question-and-answer set likely to help other people at this point, so unless we're all inclined to do some editing to improve quality, it might make sense just to delete the question.

Comment: ...actually, I found some already-answered duplicates, which lets us use this as a pointer to the others, so it makes sense to keep it around undeleted to use as a marker.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. If I had managed to find that first linked article, I wouldn't be here! Anything I can do to this question to make it more useful for a visitor?